# Airflow - localhost

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I am a beginner of airflow. I googled about the error of local airflow a lot but I couldn't find the answer..
I used to open local airflow and there was no problem.
But suddenly, when I run docker airflow-init-1 container is broken. Whenever I try to run the docker, it becomes 'Exited'. But other containers are not broken.
And this is the error log.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpUvf.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJhid.png)
These are what I tried.

1. airflow db upgrade
   -> zsh: command not found: airflow
2. check configuration.py
   -> it is not the old setting unlike the error said
3. pip uninstall airflow
   -> WARNING: Skipping airflow as it is not installed.
4. pip3 uninstall airflow
   -> WARNING: Skipping airflow as it is not installed.

Could anyone recommend any method that I can try?

```
2023-01-30 16:46:56 Postgres is up - executing command
**2023-01-30 16:47:00 /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:538: DeprecationWarning: The sql_alchemy_conn option in [core] has been moved to the sql_alchemy_conn option in [database] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
**2023-01-30 16:47:00   option = self._get_environment_variables(deprecated_key, deprecated_section, key, section)
2023-01-30 16:47:02 INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
2023-01-30 16:47:02 INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
2023-01-30 16:47:04 Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-01-30 16:47:04   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 233, in _catch_revision_errors
2023-01-30 16:47:00 
2023-01-30 16:47:02 DB: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:***@postgres/airflow

2023-01-30 16:47:04     raise util.CommandError(err.args[0]) from err
2023-01-30 16:47:04 alembic.util.exc.CommandError: Requested revision a13f7613ad25 overlaps with other requested revisions 13eb55f81627
2023-01-30 16:47:05 /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:538: DeprecationWarning: The sql_alchemy_conn option in [core] has been moved to the sql_alchemy_conn option in [database] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
2023-01-30 16:47:05   option = self._get_environment_variables(deprecated_key, deprecated_section, key, section)
2023-01-30 16:47:06 /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:538 DeprecationWarning: The sql_alchemy_conn option in [core] has been moved to the sql_alchemy_conn option in [database] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
2023-01-30 16:47:07 ERROR: You need to upgrade the database. Please run `airflow db upgrade`. Make sure the command is run using Airflow version 2.3.4.
2023-01-30 16:47:08 /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:538: DeprecationWarning: The sql_alchemy_conn option in [core] has been moved to the sql_alchemy_conn option in [database] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
2023-01-30 16:47:08   option = self._get_environment_variables(deprecated_key, deprecated_section, key, section)
2023-01-30 16:47:08 2.3.4
```

Comment: Its not very clear how are you running the Airflow. 

Can you try running using docker-compose, here's official airflow documentation https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I can only provide you with a few steps:

1. Try to rebuild the docker
2. Try to use the latest airflow version
3. Try to use this beginner [guide](https://youtu.be/K9AnJ9_ZAXE)